# Navigate to a page in external folder using expo-router

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, mobile, expo, expo-router

I am creating a mobile app using React Native and Expo and I aam still new to this. [This image shows how my directory tree looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5FFm.png)
I have an Edit Profile button in my app/tabs/users/[id].js file and I want the user when pressed to navigate to app/screens/editprofile.js page. I am using expo router and I have tried to use the  component imported from expo-router with an href attribute but it is not working. I also tried the . Any advice would be helpful and please let me know if the file division should be done in another way!

```
<TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("SignUp");
        }}
      >
```

Many thanks!

I was expecting to have access to navigate to Screens/EditProfile.js when pressing the link but I could't